# Sort elements with the fewest comparisons possible

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, comparison

I have a folder full of images. There are too many to just 'rank'. I made a program that shows two at a time and let's the user pick which one of the two is better. At the end I would like all of the photos to be ordered from best to worst.

I am purely trying to optimize for the fewest amount of comparisons possible. I don't care if the program runs in n cubed time. I've read the other questions here with similar questions but I'm looking for something more advanced.

I'm thinking maybe some sort of algorithm that based on what comparisons you've already made, the program chooses two images to compare that will offer the most information. Maybe even an algorithm that makes complex connections to help determine the orders and potential orders.

Like I said I don't care if it is slow just purely trying to minimize comparisons

Comment: What makes you think that "which do you like better" is a total-order relation?  In particular, human taste preferences often don't follow the rule of transitivity, i.e., a < b, b < c => a < c.

Comment: Human taste is also pretty fickle. A person could say a < b, and five minutes later say a > b.

Comment: looking at DanielHsH's answer, it's looking like "what is the name of my problem"-type of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If total order exists, you need at least n*log2(n) comparisons. It can be easily proved mathematically. No way around. So regular sorting algorithms in n*log(n) will do the job.

What you are trying to do is called 'topological sort'. Google it and read about it in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). You can achieve partial sorts in less comparisons. Its kind of a graduate sort. The more comparisons you get, the better the result will be.

However, what do you do if no total order exists? Humans are not able to generate a total order for subjective tasks.
For example picture 1 is better than 2, 2 is better than 3 but 3 is better than 1.
In this case no sorting algorithm can produce a permutation which will match all the decisions. During topological sort, you can detect those inconsitent decisions and get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will check that out. But I disagree that you always need nlog2(n) comparisons. If the algorithm is designed to pick the best comparisons you could achieve a lot less. Example: 4 elements: 0, 1, 2, 3. The user has said that 1 > 0 and that 3 > 2. If the algorithm does complex calculations you could find that 2 and 1 would be a good pair to compare next. And if the user says that 2 > 1 then we have sorted 4 elements in 3 comparisons.

Comment: @ThatOneGuyInXNA: First, if 1>0 and 3>2, then you want to compare 1 and 3. And when you determine that 3>1, you still have to compare 1 with 2 to determine which is next, and then you have to compare the final two. You can't get a complete ordering of 4 items in 3 comparisons.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Assuming transitivity is true (which it is in my case). Then if 3>2 and 1>0, then if the user says that 2>1 then you can assume that 3>2>1>0. Checking 3>1 would be redundant because 3>2>1. This is why when just 3>2 and 1>0 is known, picking 2 and 1 to compare, would hold a lot more information then any other comparison.

Comment: I agree that in a very specific cases one might need less comparisons. For examples, if all the N elements in an array are equal, you will need at most N-1 comparisons. But in general case (when you assume all possible permutations of array are valid) it is incorrect. Assuming all elements in array are unique you have N! possible permutations. Each comparison reduces yields at most 2 answers with new information (bigger/smaller) so each comparison reduces the amount of permutation by at most 2. The amount of comparisons needed is ~log(N!).

Comment: Moreover: note that even if you manage to shave off a few comparisons in a specific cases, the result will be less stable. A one arbitrary decision of human subject may hugely change the outcome. Image a specific case: images A and B seems equally likable, so people tend to prefer one of the almost randomly. You expect a stable sorting to not be affected by such unimportant decisions. But, In your example, this will hugely affect the result.

Comment: @ThatOneGuyInXNA: Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list. In particular, note that it takes five comparisons to fully sort four items. If you can do it in fewer comparisons, you should publish the proof.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a sorting algorithm - [pick one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms). Most algorithms just need a comparison function (`a < b?`). This is when you show the user two pictures and he has to choose the better one.

You might wan't to read trough some of the algorithms and choose the best one for you. E.g. on quicksort, you would pick a random picture and the user have to compare this picture against **all** other pictures in the first round - might be too boring from the end user perspective.

Comment: No, he's not looking for a traditional sorting algorithm. And what you describe for quicksort is more along the lines of how selection sort works.

Comment: When we are talking about the same quicksort, the user need to compare one picture to all others _on the first round_ . But granted: DanielHsH's answer is pointing in a more reasonable direction for this problem - learned something new today.